# Infinite List causes duplication when app is moved to background state and again to foreground state

Tags: listview, dart, flutter, paging

I am trying to load bunch of names from an api using `ListView` builder.
My `api` has a parameter called index which needs to be increased by 50 every time user reaches end of the list
so i have attached a `ScrollController` to my `ListView`.
The value of index at the start is 0.

I am calling the `api` first in the `initState`

Follwoing is my code when user reaches end of the list

```
 scrollController.addListener(() {
      if (scrollController.position.pixels ==
          scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent) {
        index += 50;

        //Calling the api again here
      }
    });
```

Now using this way the list loads fine. Suppose the user loaded all the data and suppose the index is 250, and now the user decides 
to put the app in the background and after some time opens the app again, the last 50 items are added again to my list which i don't understand why.

I am using a `StreamBuilder` with `bloc` pattern

```
if (snapshot.data != null) {
 studentList.addAll(snapshot.data.studentList);
}
```

I tired the distinct operator but it does not work for my case

```
Observable<StudentListModel> get studentList => _studentList.stream.distinct();
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing this is your problem.

```
if (snapshot.data != null) {
  studentList.addAll(snapshot.data.studentList);
}
```

You are adding on top of the first 50 retrieved students, 100 students, where 50 of them are repeated.
You can change your code to:

```
if (snapshot.data != null) {
  studentList = snapshot.data.studentList;
}
```

Comment: if i reassign the list instead of adding it to it then the first 50 items will be lost as soon as the scroll listener loads the next 50 item. I need to add it to my list.

Comment: Then I guess the problem is that the streamBuilder is calling build again and you are adding to the list unconditionally. You can try this operator over the stream of students. https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-async/Stream/distinct.html

Comment: I tried the distinct operator but it does not solve the issue